# MUX re-configuration speed

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am looking for some high voltage, high channel, analog multiplexers that I can change the configuration of very fast and I am just wondering if I am looking at this data correctly.

When I look at the IC on 
[mouser](http://www.mouser.se/ProductDetail/Analog-Devices/AD75019JPZ/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMud93iq7xrBrWoLPJZxA8o1BTemJnXt8aM%3d)
 it says that the bandwidth of the circuit is 20MHz and when I then go and check the load time on the datasheet it says that the serial clock is capable of working at 5MHz which makes it much slower since you need to send a bit-stream in order to program it....

So I guess it's the serial clock which is the bottle neck for this component right? If you would compare it with for example [this](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/465/cd22m3494-553706.pdf) from Intersil which is adressed in parallel.

Comment: I am not sure what the analogue bandwidth of the switched signals should have to do with the speed the serial communication works at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "switch frequency response" refers to the frequency of the signal passing through the switch. It is not related to how quickly the switch can be reconfigured. For example there are rf switches that can carry 20 GHz signals but require milliseconds to change configuration.

You are correct to look at the digital IO characteristics, particularly the timing characteristics on page 3 of the datasheet, to determine how quickly the switch can be reconfigured.